# And like operator in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I can't see any **AND** or **OR** kind of operator usually found in other languages which can be combined with if conditionals for checking more than one condition.

How to achieve these type of tasks in Racket ?

I know about `cond` but I cannot think a way in which it solves my problem.

Comment: `and` is the first hit if you search for "and" in the racket manual; it's in the section titled "Conditionals: if, cond, and, and or".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there: [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=and#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/letstx-scheme..rkt%29._and%29%29)

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.3.5 [3m].
Language: racket [custom].
> (and (even? 10) (odd? 10))
#f
> (or (even? 10) (odd? 10))
#t
```